# Does the Lie Bracket automatically exist?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $g$ be a Matrix Lie Group. The Lie Algebra of $g := Lie(g)$ is defined as $ Lie(g) = \{ \dot{\gamma}(0) | \gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \rightarrow g, \gamma \in C^1,  \gamma(0) =  \mathbb{I} \} $

Suppose I already calculated $Lie(g)$ for my Matrix Lie Group, i.e. I showed the two inclusions $Lie(g) \subseteq \{ \dot{\gamma}(0) | \gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \rightarrow g, \gamma \in C^1,  \gamma(0) =  \mathbb{I} \} $ and $Lie(g) \supseteq  \{ \dot{\gamma}(0) | \gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \rightarrow g, \gamma \in C^1,  \gamma(0) =  \mathbb{I} \}  $

What about the Lie Bracket? If I'm only interested in the actual set $Lie(g)$ I don't necessarily have to compute what the Lie Bracket looks like, right? It exists anyway and since I'm only intersted in knowing what the elements of $Lie(g)$ look like, I'm done.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you showed those inclusions, isn't that the definition? Perhaps you have another definition for $Lie(g)$ which you did not write here. That said, a matrix Lie group has the commutator bracket so if $A,B \in Lie(g)$ then you should be able to show $[A,B] \in Lie(g)$. For example, for $sl(n)$ the Lie algebra of $Sl(n)$ given by $det(B)=1$ the identity $det(e^A) = e^{tr(A)}$ indicates $tr(A)=0$ for $A \in sl(n)$. However, $tr([A,B]) = tr(AB-BA) = tr(AB)-tr(BA)=0$ so the algebra closes under $[,]$.

Comment: With these two inclusions I mean the following: For example if $g = SO(3)$ then we can differentiate $I = \gamma \gamma^T$ and get the condition that for $v \in Lie(SO(3))$ it has to hold that $v + v^T = 0$. Now I would define $Lie(g) = \{ v \in Mat_3(\mathbb{R}) | v + v^T = 0  \}$ but you'd have to show that if $y(t) = exp(t v)$ then the relation in $SO(3)$ i.e. $y \cdot y^T = 1$ holds aswell. That's what I mean with the two inclusions. Does that make more sense?